# window.onerror line number always 1

Tags: javascript

I want to get a mail if an error occurs in my program. This works fine:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
    prog = "fehler";
    var urlJ = server + prog + querystrJsonO + "&qu=" + qu + "&msg=" + msg + "&line=" + line + "&col=" + col;
    $.getJSON(urlJ, function(data) {});
};
```

But I get only linenumber 1.

My code is not minified. What can I do to get the linenumber of the error?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow, tell us what error are you getting, so we can help you better! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a XMLHttpRequest inside the function and send a get request to your server with a phone script ready to receive the parameters. Then you can use mail() function to send yourself mail regarding problem. Am using it hope it sounds well to you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The json and email works fine. But I get the linenumber 1 of the error.